# Reading a Textfile from SVN in C#

Tags: c#, svn, ldap, text-files

*Reworked Question

I want to connect to our company SVN using SharpSVN in c# and read a textfile located in a folder.

The problem is, that our SVN needs authentication with LDAP and because of the security i can not write the username / password in the code.

So i need a way to load the current username + password from our LDAP Server and create a connection with SharpSVN to the specific folder.

Is there any way to do so, or is it not possible to securely work with c# code to make a SVN connection using LDAP data?

Comment: Try doing WebClient.DownloadString instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Refused during Security - as the SVN we are using needs authentication

Comment: Could you please edit your post with code snippet?